# Angular with Service Worker doesn't update website when user renavigates to the website

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I have an angular application and I'm trying to setup software updates with the ServiceWorker module.

I've got things setup so that if a user is presently on the website and if I push out a new version of my website then the next time I do `this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate()` it will detect a new version of the website is available. (this is setup to check every 30 minutes)

My issue is that when a person (who had previously visited my website) comes to my website after an update was pushed (say I deploy today in the morning and the user navigates to the website this evening) then they will see the old website for about half a minute then the website will detect a new updated website. At which point I display a message that they should update/reload the website.

I'd like it so whenever a user comes to my site that they grab a fresh current website.

... I'm just imagining that, as it is currently, I can see a person who is an infrequent user getting annoyed that every time they come to my site they're instructed to update the website.

Here's how I register the service worker in app.module.ts

[image]

Here's how I check for updates (currently checking every 30 minutes)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how is it possible that a user can get a different version of a website at the same url?

Comment: Say a user visits my website yesterday, they see verison 1 of my website, they then close their browser. Today I deploy version 2 of the website. Tomorrow the same user visits my website on the same computer and same browser. They SHOULD see version 2 of my website, but they're currently see version 1 of my website. This is the issue I'm trying to fix. If they wait around about 10-20sec then Angular Software Updates ends up checking for updates and can see there's a version mismatch. But it's too late now, the user is already on Version 1 and I need to "annoy" the user by reloading their page.

Comment: That's not how websites work normally. You just host index.html at a url, and if you push out a new version it overwrites your old one. So what you're saying makes no sense to me.

Comment: What I do is once the service worker detects a new version, the next time a routing event occurs I install it and then redirect the browser to the URL they were trying to get to so the new version of the app is bootstrapped.  It avoids having to tell the user you are doing it, which seems strange on a "normal" website.

Answer (score 0):

There is another event you should look for which is the 'VERSION_DETECTED', then call this.swUpdate.activateUpdate(). This method will trigger the 'VERSION_READY' event when done.
An exemple of my implementation :

```
this.swUpdate.versionUpdates.pipe(
                tap(update => {
                    if (update.type === 'VERSION_DETECTED') {
                        // activateUpdate() will trigger the 'VERSION_READY' or 'VERSION_INSTALLATION_FAILED' event when done
                        console.log('New server version detected, trying to install...');
                        this.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then();
                    }
                    if (update.type === 'VERSION_READY') {
                        // this._reloadPage will be set to true, asking a full page reload on next navigation
                        console.log('New server version installed');
                        this.notify(false);
                    }
                    if (update.type === 'VERSION_INSTALLATION_FAILED') {
                        // this._clearCacheAndReload will be set to true, asking a cache clear and full page reload on next navigation
                        console.warn('Error while installing update, cache will be cleared and page reloaded');
                        this.notify(true);
                    }
                    // another event type possible is 'NO_NEW_VERSION_DETECTED', we don't need to handle it
                })
            ).subscribe();
```